# How does "and not c.append(x)" works here?

Tags: python, filtering, list-comprehension

Trying to solve simple exercise: find common part of two lists without repetitions using list comprehension. Found the solution online but don't understand the last bit. It's a compound filter, but I don't get how "not c.append(elem)" resolves to a boolean.

```
from random import randrange

a = []
b = []
c = []

for x in range(randrange(15, 20)):
    a.append(randrange(1, 20))
    b.append(randrange(1, 20))

a.sort()

print(a)
print(b)

c = [elem for elem in a if elem in b and elem not in c and not c.append(elem)]
print(c)
```

It's only about "and not c.append(elem)".

Comment: This is a less beautiful way to put a side effect into a comprehension. It is OK not to memorize this for further programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take this apart:

```
... elem not in c and not c.append(elem)
```

This part first checks if `elem` is in `c` (**Note**: The previous `c` declared before as `c = []`), and if it's not, append it to `c`. Since `list.append` always returns `None`, which is a falsey value. The `not` before it inverts the result into `True`, so the element is also picked up by the list comprehension.

The code effectively filters out unique common elements in `a` and `b` and is equivalent to the following code:

```py
list_comp_result = []
for elem in a:
    if elem in b:
        if elem not in c:
            c.append(elem)  # <-- always None
            list_comp_result.append(elem)
```

Answer (score 0):

it is only used to append elem

```
c.append(elem) = None
```

not c.append(elem) always True

Comment: in this case。you can use:```d= list(set(a) & set(b))```

Comment: + if not use ```and not c.append(elem)```   
        in processing  ，  ```c  = []```  until [...] finish , c = [...]'s result 。
+ if  use ```and not c.append(elem)]```  then  
in processing ,  c is changed  
code1 =
```
c=[elem for elem in a if elem in b and elem not in c and not c.append(elem)]
print(c)
```
code2=
```
[elem for elem in a if elem in b and elem not in c and not c.append(elem)]
print(c)
```
code3=
```
for elem in a:
    if elem in b:
        if elem not in c:
            c.append(elem)
print(c)
```
code1 = code2 =code3